# Python Syntax Unknown

Tags: python

I just came across an assignment like this in python. I checked everywhere to see what this was but couldn't find it. What does this mean in python?

```
 total_mask |= is_NA
```

The operator in the middle is confusing me.

Thanks

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: Generally speaking, `A ?= B` is the same as `A = A ? B`, for most any operator you care to replace the question mark with.

Comment: That operator (and many like it) were introduced in [PEP 203](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements

Answer (score 3):

It's just an operator of logical OR.
If `total_mask` is

```
0011101010101001110
```

and `is_NA` is

```
0000000000000100000
```

then `total_mask` will become

```
0011101010101101110
```

in this case it's just like addition.
*EDIT*: of course the numbers are here written in binary.
In Python you can convert a number to a binary string using the `bin` function, for example

```
>>> bin(99)
'0b1100011'
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as

```
total_mask = total_mask|is_NA
```

Comment: @wim care to explain?

Comment: consider the case of sets, where this operator means in-place union.  the |= operator (which slots into `set.__ior__`) will preserve the identity of the set, whereas the method you have shown will create a new set.  this can have side effects for other references to the same set.